# Flexible line break with css only (at fixed point)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to fluidly break or join text at linebreak (using responsive media queries)
But the breaking point must be pre-set (not with white-space: xxx)

I have this html:

```
<h1>This is a very <br />Very long text menu</h1>
<h1>This is a short one</h1>
```

I'm thinking, it would be best to surround the last line (in first h1) in a span, and then style that span

Like so:

```
<h1>This is a very <span>very long text menu</span></h1>
<h1>This is a short one</h1>
```

But what do I write in css to make that span break into a second line? display: block?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    h1 span {
        // show it at it's own line underneath
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use display block.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    h1 span {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Comment: hehe yes ok. It's funny when you realize the answer while asking the question here at S.O. :) thanks